# JPanel not adding BorderLayout components as expected

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I'm trying for quite some time now to find what the problem but to no avail ,its a quite simple one really, the `BorderLayout` won't add the button to the correct place on the screen (South).

I don't want to add the button to the `JPanel` itself, I want to make a secondary panel, add that panel to the main panel and the button to the secondary panel, here the simple code:

```
public class panelClass extends JPanel{

JPanel secondaryPanel = new JPanel();
JButton btn = new JButton("Test");

public panelClass(){
    add(secondaryPanel);
    secondaryPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    secondaryPanel.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}}
```

The button shows up in the upper-middle part of the screen, like a regular
`FlowLayout`, instead in the lower-middle part like I expected.

Comment: `public class panelClass extends JPanel{` Don't extend components unless changing existing functionality.  Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 3):

this line is the problem

```
add(secondaryPanel);
```

default layout of jpanel is `flow layout` .so when you add secondary panel to main panel secondary panel added to upper-middle position of main panel.that's why you see button shows up in the upper-middle part of the screen, like a regular `flowLayout`.if you set a background color to secondary panel you can clearly see the problem yourself

add appropriate layout to  your main panel .for example

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(secondaryPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```